# Does querySelectorAll() only work with one html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two html files `register.html` and `login.html`.

When you run my snippet and click on the eyes the type of the input changes from password to text. Here on Stackoverflow it works but when I split them into the two above mentioned html files only the eye on `register.html` works. The eye on `login.html` doesn't change at all and moreover doesn't even log `console.log(eye.length);`. The output is then `1`. Why?

And yes I added the script in both files with `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`

```js
let eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');
console.log(eye.length);
let pass = document.querySelectorAll('.password');
eye.forEach(function (v, i) {
    v.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
        const type = pass[i].getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
        pass[i].setAttribute('type', type);
    })
});
```

```css
.fa-eye {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">

register.html
<div class="password-container">
    <input class="input-field-register password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort" maxlength="16">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye eye"></i>
</div>

login.html
<div class="password-container">
    <input class="input-field-login password"type="password" placeholder="Passwort" maxlength="16">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye eye"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you loading/opening/viewing those files? Is the element actually in the DOM yet?

Comment: Aside: _please_ put those icons into actual buttons.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes how can I check that? I uploaded my version on `http://eis2.de`. When you click `Anmelden` on the top the eye is not working. However, when you continue on `Registrieren` the eye is working.

Comment: How do you load multiple HTML files at in one webpage? You can't modify another webpage using DOM API.

Comment: @jabaa In my `index.html` in the <head> I call `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/login.html'>`. In the login.html I then have two buttons on the top `Anmelden` and `Registrieren` which do this: `<a href="login.html">Anmelden</a>` and `<a href="register.html">Registrieren</a>`

Comment: So you have 3 different, unrelated webpages, `index.html`, `login.html` and `register.html`. `index.html` redirects to `login.html` and `login.html` has a link to `register.html`? You can't modify one webpage from another webpage. Do all webpages load the script?

Comment: Yeah and from 'register.html' there is also a redirection to 'login.html'. How do I fix that problem so that I can modify one webpage from another ?

Comment: Everytime you load a new webpage, everything is reset. Even if you change something in `login.html`, go to `register.html` and go back to `login.html`, the changes are gone. You can either store the changes in a storage or use the URL, to store the state. But this topic is a different questions.

Answer (score 3):

QuerySelectorAll() only works on elements which are available in rendered DOM at a time